# Supplying multiple arguments in emblem.js helper invocation

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, emblem.js

Let's say, I would like to call an Ember Handlebars helper from an emblem.js template.

I have declared the helper through (CoffeeScript syntax):

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper 't', (key, value, context) ->
    ...
```

When attempting to invoke the helper from emblem using

```
= t "my.i18n.key", "val", count: 42
```

`key` is assigned correctly, all but the first arguments are dropped and the second argument is replaced by some options hash as would be the case for a bound helper (the third argument is undefined).

Is there any way to invoke a helper in emblem.js with more than a single argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can only pass one value, but you can use the options hash with many bound/computed properties like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('truncatedQuery', 
  function truncatedQueryHelper(value, options) {
    console.log('value', value, 'options:', 
      options.hash['key1'], options.hash['key2'], options.hash['key3']);
  // do work...
   return somethingUseful;
});
```

And in your template use `optionsHashKeyBinding=propertyOnControllerName` like this:

```
<div class='truncated-query'>
  {{truncatedQuery 'value' key1Binding=prop1 key2Binding=prop2 key3=42}}
</div>
```

Where `prop1` and `prop2` are on the controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  prop1: 'foo',
  prop2: function() {
    return this.get('prop1') + 'bar';
  }.property('prop1'),
});
```